# A container for storing java.util.concurrent.Future instances

Tags: java

I'm submitting `Callable`s to an `ExecutorService` on behalf of a particular *Job* (we can regard a Job as a subset of things that get ran on the executor service).

Of course, on submission of a `Callable`, I get back a `Future`.

I need to be able to interrupt the `Future`s submitted on behalf of a particular Job. In order to implement this, I'm tempted to use a `java.utils.TreeSet` embedded into my `Job` class. But, I'm concerned about the distinctness of each `Future`: would they occupy unique positions in the `TreeSet`? If not, then is there a better container to use?

One solution, if a container is not up to it, would be to extend `ExecutorService` and increment an counter on each submission, then use that counter as some kind of hash which would guarantee uniqueness. But that's an overhead I'm keen to avoid, especially if my concerns are unfounded.

Comment: To clarify: Is it right that there is a 1:n relation between "Job" and "Callable": That is, each Job consists of several Callables, and when one Job should be cancelled, then all the Futures of its Callables should be cancelled?

Comment: @Marco13: yes that is correct.

Comment: OK, the `ArrayList` was accepted now, otherwise I had suggested something like a `Map<Job, Collection<Future>>` (or analogously, a Guava `Multimap`) to easily manage the relationship between Jobs and Futures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A TreeSet is a sorted set, and you don't need to sort your futures.

You don't need to deal with duplicates either, so a Set is not necessary.

Simply using an `ArrayList` should be fine.

Comment: Thanks JB Nizet: This clearly demonstrates the importance of collaboration in software development; the value of a second pair of eyes cannot be overestimated.

Answer (score 0):

Since future does not have its own implementation for `equals` it will fall back on the `this==obj` from `Object`. Since normally the `ExecutorService` will return distinct objects you should be fine.

However, I'm thinking any container (list, set, array,...) should do so to be certain I'd advise using an `(Array)List`.

Answer (score 0):

If I need to lookup a future, I'll store it in a map. With the id as key and the future as value.